# 6 x 12 header capability

Tags: beam, span-tables

I need to support a ridge beam on one end with a Douglas fir 6 x 12 x 12 ft long header. The load will be on a single point in the center and will be about 8000 lbs total. I can't tolerate sag as there is an expensive door/window assembly installed below. I cannot find single point header tables anywhere and don't care to enlist an engineer as most will not work on a single component basis. My experience and gut says it's good but I want to prove the math. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of load will be 8000 lb single point? How would this single point load be attached to this beam? You have to describe the situation in detail so potential commenters can know the implications of an opinion that might be wrong or even just questionable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a 6 x 12 Douglas Fir-Larch (#2 and better) with a 12’ span will support 8,000 lbs. at mid-span. It’s deflection will be less than 1/3 inch when fully loaded.

If the 6 x 12 is a Select Structural, then it will support 10,300 lbs. and deflect about 1/4”.

BTW, I recommend the window (vinyl, wood, whatever) that you are going to install below this beam should NOT be secured at the head in the middle one-half of the span.